# ReactJS: What's the real world use of Immutability Helpers in React?

Tags: immutability, reactjs

React's official document provide [Immutability Helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

What would be some real world usage of such helpers? I think I am missing something really basic here.

Answer (score 7):

React assumes that objects set in state are immutable, which means that if you want to add or remove some element inside your array you should create new one with added element keeping previous array untouched:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = React.addons.update(a, {'$push': [4] });
console.log(a); // [1, 2, 3];
console.log(b); // [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

By using immutable objects you can easily check if content of object has changed:

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { elements: [1, 2, 3] };
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        var newVal = this.state.elements.length + 1;
        this.setState({
            elements: React.addons.update(this.state.elements, { '$push': [ newVal ] })
        })
    },
    shouldComponentUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState) {
        return this.state.elements !== nextState.elements;
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>{ this.state.elements.join(', ') }</div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: `push` is a basic command that could also be achieved using `concat`. But the real beauty comes when you have deep nested arrays or objects of data.

Answer (score 2):

ReactJS state should preferably be **immutable**. Meaning that, everytime `render()` is called, `this.state` should be a different object. That is: `oldState == newState` is false and `oldState.someProp == newState.someProp` is also false.

So, for simple state objects, there's no doubt they should be cloned. However, if your state object is very complex and deep, cloning the entire state might impact performance. Because of that, React's immutability helpers is smart and it only clones the objects that it thinks it should clone.

This is how you do it when you clone the state by yourself:

```
onTextChange: function(event) {
    let updatedState = _.extend({}, this.state); // this will CLONE the state. I'm using underscore just for simplicity.
    updatedState.text = event.text;
    this.setState(updatedState);
}
```

This is how you do it when you let React's immutability helpers determine which objects it should actually clone:

```
onTextChange: function(event) {
    let updatedState = React.addons.update(this.state, { text: {$set: event.text} });
    this.setState(updatedState);
}
```

The above example will perform better then the first one when the `state` is too complex and deep.

Answer (score 2):

React application prefer immutability, there are two ways (from Facebook) to support immutability,  one is to use [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) that is a complete immutability library, another one is the [immutable helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) that is a lightweight helper. You only need to choose one to use in one project.

The only disadvantege of [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) is that it leak itself throughout your entire application including the Stores and View Components, e.g.,

```
// Stores
props = props.updateIn(['value', 'count'], count => count + 1);

// View Components
render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.getIn("value", "count")}</div>;
}
```

If you use [immutable helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), you can encapsulate the immutability operations at the place where updates happen (such as Stores and Redux Reducers). Therefore, your View Components can be more reusable.

```
// Stores or Reducers
props = update(props, {
    value: {count: {$set: 7}}
};

// View Components can continue to use Plain Old JavaSript Object
render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.value.count}</div>;
}
```

Comment: You may also use https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object) in your React components, but without the magic keywords: $set, $push, etc.